# Converting into rectangular form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I have 2 related questions:

First:

> Let $z_1 = 2+2i$ and $z_2 = 2-2i$.  Find $z_1z_2 $ in rectangular form.

I have no idea...

I'm also clueless about this question:

> Change the following to rectangular:
>   $$r=\frac{9}{5-4\cos(\theta)}$$

The answer for the first one according to my answer key is $8$.  And the answer for second one is

$$ 9x^2 - 72x + 25y^2 - 81 = 0 $$

Comment: The second question and answer do not match at all.  The question is an expression depending on theta.  The answer is an equation.   It seems there should be $=r$ or something like that in the question.

Comment: @RossMillikan in the anwser key it says that... I dont know why but, it says the same as above..

Comment: I suspect the problem is the question.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Do you want me to take a picture of my test review and anwser key @RossMillikan ? Will it help you understand better?

Comment: Sure, take a picture of the second question from the test review because as stated here it doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: @Bye_World Its in my picture header.. I dont know why Images are so Big!

Comment: OK, you were just missing the "$r=$" part.  I added it and removed the picture.

Comment: Oh you purposely removed picture.. sorry i didnt know.

Comment: @Bye_World You know how to do it now? Cause im till confused :/

Comment: @RossMillikan: I don't see a problem, the question and the answer do match. Polar to Cartesian transform.

Comment: @Dsafds: shame on you for being unable to solve the first part, an elementary multiply !

Comment: @YvesDaoust:  they do now.  For a long time the question did not include $r=$, so we just had the expression on the right.

Comment: @RossMillikan: sorry, couldn't know that. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, we have two concepts going on that while related, are probably best learned independently, and then then the relationship can be explained.

$|z|$ is the distance $z$ is from the origin.

If $z = x+ iy, |z| = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$

If $z$ is in polar form $z = \rho (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta), |z| = \rho$

To find $|z_1z_2|$, you have choice, you can multiply them together, find the result, and then use the formula above to find the answer.  However, it is nature of complex numbers that $|z_1z_2| = |z_1||z_2|$

Whoops, answering a different question... I am not going to delete this, because it is good to know.
$z_1 = a + i\,b\\ 
z_2 = x + i\,y \\
z_1z_2 = (a + i\,b)(x + i\,y) = (ax + i\,bx + i\,ay + i^2\,by)$

$i^2 = -1$, and you can combine the $i$ terms.

$z_1z_2 = (ax - by)  + i\,(ay + bx)$

If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in polar...

$z_1 = \rho_1 (\cos \theta + i \sin\theta)\\ 
z_2 = \rho_2 (\cos \phi + i \sin\phi)\\ 
z_1z_2 =\rho_1\rho_2 (\cos\theta\cos\phi - \sin\theta \sin\phi + i(\sin\theta \cos \phi + \cos \theta \sin \phi)\\
z_1z_2 =\rho_1\rho_2 (\cos(\theta+\phi) + i\sin(\theta+\phi))$

Converting equations in polar form to rectangular, and vice versa... know this.

$x = r \cos \theta\\
y = r \sin \theta\\
r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

It is not an equation if you don't have an equals sign.  What you have above is an expression with no context, and there is nothing to do with it...

$r = \frac{9}{5-4\cos\theta}$

Do some algebra to turn that $\cos \theta$ into an $r\cos\theta$ and then say $r\cos\theta = x.$

And, you will have a leftover $r,$ isolate it, square both sides, and $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

~~~~~~

$r = \frac{9}{5-4\cos\theta}\\
r(5-4\cos\theta) = 9\\
5r - 4r\cos\theta = 9\\
r\cos\theta = x\\
5r - 4x = 9\\
5r =9+4x\\
25r^2 =(9+4x)^2\\
25r^2 =81+72x + 16x^2\\
r^2 = x^2 + y^2\\
25(x^2 + y^2) =81+72x + 16x^2\\
9x^2 - 72 x + 25y^2 =81\\
$

Now, if you wanted to you could put it into standard form for an ellipse, but it doesn't sound that that is really necessary.

Comment: But i dont know how to do second problem!

Comment: Multiply though by $(5-4\cos\theta),$ to get rid of the fraction.  Distribute the r.  replace $r\cos\theta$ with $x.$  Isolate $r.$  square both sides.  Replace $r^2,$ with $x^2 + y^2.$

Comment: Where am I losing you?  Bye World has provided 2 step-by-step solutions.  And, I thought I had pretty clearly explained the process.

Comment: In ByeWorld Comments you can see i have a major problem

Comment: How about this?

Comment: Why is it diffrent from my original anwser????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39984/discussion-between-doug-m-and-dsafds).

Comment: In your final step, you should have $9x^2 - 72x + 25y^2 = 81$ since $25x^2 - 16x^2 = 9x^2$.

Comment: For some reason i understand today @DougM

Comment: For some reason i understand today @N.F.Taussig

Comment: THanks a lot i understand a lot now.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply complex numbers, you just use the distributive property and the fact that $i^2=-1$.  So $(2+2i)(2-2i)=2\cdot 2 + 2i \cdot 2 +2 \cdot (-2i)+2i \cdot (-2i)$  Can you keep going?  Maybe you recognize the factorization of the difference of squares, which would make this example easier.

Comment: I cant actually.. how does it become 8?

Comment: I got $4 + 4i^2$ ...

Comment: No, you lost a minus sign in the last term.  When you put that back and use $i^2=-1$ you will get $8$

Comment: Omg! i forgot $i^2 = -1$.. So stupid!

Comment: Also notice that $z_2$ is the conjugate of $z_1$ i.e. $z_2 = z^*$. Use the property: $zz^* = |z|^2$ to see that it equals 8.

Answer (score 1):

$$r=\frac9{5-4\cos(\theta)},\\
5r-4r\cos(\theta)=5r-4x=9,\\
25r^2=25(x^2+y^2)=(9+4x)^2=81+72x+16x^2.$$

Hence,

$$9x^2-72x+25y^2-81=0.$$

This is a cute ellipse.

Comment: Yves how did you transform from $r=95−4cos(θ),5r−4rcos(θ)=5r−4x=9,25r2=25(x2+y2)=(9+4x)2=$ To the anwser? And also can you give me the formulas for Ellipse, i need them for my test. Thankyou good sir!

Comment: @Dsafds: move the terms in the same member, this is elementary.

Comment: Ok Yves... but how is $5r−4x$ equal to $9$ ??

Comment: @Dsafds: one row above.

Comment: DId you multiply it by $\frac{1}{r}$ or something?? Your equation is getting confusing... And how is $5r-4x$ equal to $9$

Comment: @Dsafds: I just moved the denominator.

Comment: Ok i understood as i saw Doug M.. Now can you give me the elipse and hyperbbola formulas>

Comment: Like how did you do your last step of conversion... Thats where i got tricked of....

Comment: How in the world is it a cute ellipse?

Comment: Nvm we dont need to convert to ellipse... Thanyou